# Jquery loaded, but $ is not defined

Tags: php, jquery, web-hosting

On my local machine(Windows) jquery works. But, when hosted online(godaddy), linux server, this errors are found firebug:

```
TypeError: ajaxLocation is undefined
-Points to: ajaxLocParts = rurl.exec( ajaxLocation.toLowerCase() ) || [];

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

On the net panel, *jquery.js* file is clearly loaded.
I tried changing to cdn link, but throws another error saying : `not a valid domain.`

edit: jquery link

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="view/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

few code lines:

```
$('#area_search_field').focusout(function(){
    $('#city_suggestion_box').attr('class','city_suggestion_box_hidden');
});
```

What could be the possible problem?

Comment: the problem is... `$` is not defined. clear and simple. is `jQuery` defined?

Comment: SHow the code, then check again. The problem is quite clear here. $ is not defined. a.) invalid url trying to load a script src does not equal valid b.) you're trying to call jQuery before it is lodade.

Comment: then how does it work locally? @RPM

Comment: You're site is probably in a subdir. simply do this:

Answer (score 0):

```
view/js/jquery.js
```

What you need to do is use a fully qualified domain name prepended to that URI.

To properly fix your problem, you need to do this:

```
<script src="MYDOMAIN.tld/view/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: I told you, that in the firebug net panel, it clearly shows that the jquery file requested is loaded.

Comment: Where is the script being executed relative to your first script (jquery src), after or before?

Comment: Link to webpage to resolve this quickly and efficiently if you can share that.

Comment: does it has anything to do with os of host?

Comment: What is that site, yours?

Comment: is console.log() prevented on hosting sites?